# Bash - logging function - printf

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to create a logger for bash. The problem is that the direct print is working but the LOGGER_FUNC does not handle the array correctly.

Currently I can print the data that is supposed to be logged:

```
DEBUG_data_ARRAY=(hi ho no bugs here no)
printf "\n%s" "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}"
printf "\n%s %s" "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}"
```

Where the printf should be replaced with:

```
LOGGER_FUNC "\n%s" "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}"
LOGGER_FUNC "\n%s %s" "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}"
```

Logger function:

```
LOGGER_FUNC () {
    format=$1
    message=$2
    if [[ $VERBOSE == 0 ]]; then
        printf "${format[@]}" "${message[@]}"
    fi
    if [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]]; then
         printf "${format[@]}" "${message[@]}" >> $DEBUG_FILE
    fi
    if [[ $VERBOSE == 2 ]]; then
        printf "${format[@]}" "${message[@]}"
        printf "${format[@]}" "${message[@]}" >> $DEBUG_FILE
    fi
}
```

The expected result is the following:

```
hi 
ho 
no 
bugs
here 
no

hi ho 
no bugs
here no
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> format=$1
> message=$2
> ```

This creates two scalar variables. To make `message` an array containing `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, etc., write:

```
format=$1
message=("${@:2}")
```

Then since `format` is a scalar you can just write `$format` rather than `${format[@]}`:

```
if [[ $VERBOSE == 0 ]]; then
    printf "$format" "${message[@]}"
fi
if [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]]; then
     printf "$format" "${message[@]}" >> "$DEBUG_FILE"
fi
if [[ $VERBOSE == 2 ]]; then
     printf "$format" "${message[@]}"
     printf "$format" "${message[@]}" >> "$DEBUG_FILE"
fi
```

Comment: Wow that really made it run like a charm! Does this also mean that I cant pass two arrays or more?

Comment: Correct. There's no way to know where one array ends and the next begins.

Comment: Would it be possible if we knew the length and added that as a parameter?

Comment: @Fredrik That sounds needlessly complicated compared to simply passing one argument per message.

Comment: Usually you take 1st argument as is `"$1"` then `shift` it out, then reference the whole remaining arguments array as `"$@"`

Answer (score 1):

Using arguments as provided to the function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

LOGGER_FUNC() {
  # shellcheck disable=SC2059 # Variable format string
  printf "$@" | case $VERBOSE in
    1) cat ;;
    2) cat >>"$DEBUG_FILE" ;;
    3) tee -a "$DEBUG_FILE" ;;
  esac
}
```

Or implement a stream logger that does not need arguments for content, but take it from `stdin`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# stream_logger
# Log stdin with options
# &1: Verbose level:
#     1: stdout only
#     2: debug file only
#     3: both stdout and debug file
# &2: Optional debug file path
stream_logger() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
    cat >/dev/null
  elif [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ "$1" -eq 1 ]; then
    cat
  elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    if [ "$1" -eq 2 ]; then
      cat >>"$2"
    elif [ "$1" -eq 3 ]; then
      tee -a "$2"
    fi
  fi
}

DEBUG_data_ARRAY=(hi ho no bugs here no)

echo 'hello' | stream_logger # print nothing

# Output to stdout only
printf '\n%s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 1
printf '\n%s %s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 1

# Output to file1.log only
printf '\n%s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 2 file1.log
printf '\n%s %s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 2 file1.log

# Output to file2.log and stdout
printf '\n%s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 3 file2.log
printf '\n%s %s' "${DEBUG_data_ARRAY[@]}" | stream_logger 3 file2.log
```